# Example for connected set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $U$ be an open, bounded connected domain in $\mathbb{R} ^n$. Define $U_\epsilon=\{x\in U|dist(x,\partial U)>\epsilon\}.$

Can $U_\epsilon$ be unconnected? Anyone has example for that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868042/is-for-open-connected-u-the-set-u-varepsilon-for-small-varepsilon-connec?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for $U$ take a set in $\mathbb R^2$ that has the shape of an eight: two open balls that have a minimal overlap ($>0$ but much smaller than $\epsilon$). Then let $\epsilon$ be half of the radius of the balls. The set $U_\epsilon$ will consist of two disconnected balls of radius $\epsilon$. (I believe that you need to assume convexity of $U$ to prevent $U_\epsilon$ from being disconnected.)

Comment: I was trying to do with the 8 shape. However, the $U$ is open here.

Comment: No problem for that. Take two open balls $B_1$ and $B_2$ with radius $2 \epsilon$, the center of the first is in $(0,0)$, the one of the second is in $(4 \epsilon - \delta, 0)$. Here $\delta > 0$ is much smaller than $\epsilon$. Then let $U$ be the union of $B_1$ and $B_2$ (union of open sets is open). The set $U_\epsilon$ will be the union of two new balls, with the same centers of the others but half the radii. This set will be disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $U_{\epsilon}$ is the part of $U$ that is "far" from its boundary, like the region near the center of a large field.

So if $U$ consists of several distant large fields connected by narrow lanes, then $U_{\epsilon}$ will contain only patches in the center of the distant fields, so will be disconnected (taking $\epsilon$ sufficiently large to "flood away" the paths and leave the centers of the fields isolated).

This is the idea behind @TobiaMarcucci 's answer (and I upvoted that).