# Complement of small enough $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of boundary is connected

Tags: general-topology, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, bounded and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for which $\partial U$ is smooth. I would like to show that for $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough, the set $$U_\varepsilon := \{x \in U \ \mid \ d(x, \partial U) > \varepsilon \} $$ is connected. However, I have not managed to do so.

I have seen that there are counter-examples ([Is for open connected $U$ the set $U_\varepsilon$ for small $\varepsilon$ connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868042/is-for-open-connected-u-the-set-u-varepsilon-for-small-varepsilon-connec?noredirect=1&lq=1)) if the assumption that $\partial U$ is smooth is dropped. However, I do not see how the assumption that $\partial U$ is smooth can be used to prove that $U_\varepsilon$ is connected. I suppose that this is the same as proving that the complement of a collar neighbourhood of $\partial U$ is connected (hence why $\partial U$ needs to be smooth), but I do not know how to proceed.

This question comes up when proving, for instance, that if $u$ is a Sobolev function on $U$ with vanishing weak gradient, then it must be constant almost everywhere (the argument involves mollifying $u$ with a cut-off function, and the resulting function has vanishing weak gradient and is defined only on $U_\varepsilon$).

Comment: Assumimg that $\partial U$ is smooth means that $U$ is the interior of a smooth compact $n$-dimensional submanifold $M$ with boundary $\partial M = \partial U$. Taking a closed collar $C$ of $\partial M$ is a good idea, but I do not know how such collars are related to your $\epsilon$-definition. But certainly $M \setminus C$ is contained in some $U_\epsilon$ which may be sufficient for your purpose.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, I also am not sure anymore how the collar neighbourhood is related to the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood, since, unless $U$ is at least convex, the collar neighbourhood will not be the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood. If, instead, I would ask that the complement of a small enough collar neighbourhood of $\partial U$ is connected, then this is actually easy to prove under the additional assumption that $\partial U$ is connected. But I do not know how to generalize this.

Comment: I guess it is possible to prove that $U_\epsilon$ (for small $\epsilon$) has the form $M \setminus C$ for *some* closed collar $C$, but I do not have a proof. Anyway, $M \setminus C$ is always homeomorphic to $U = M \setminus \partial M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that holds true.
Since $U$ is open and connected it is also path connected.
Let $N$ be a unit normal vector field on $\partial U$, pointing inside $U$ (for simplicity assume that this direction is unique). Consider for $\delta>0$ the map
$$ \phi : T=T_\delta=(q,t) \in \partial U \times (0,\delta] \to 
   q+tN(q) \in {\Bbb R}^n. $$
Using that $\partial U$ is smooth and compact, we may find $\delta>0$ small enough so that the map $\phi$ has the following properties:

1. For every $(q,t)\in T$: $d(\phi(q,t),\partial U)=t$.
2. $\phi$ is a diffeo from $T$ onto $\phi(T) = U\setminus U_{\delta}$.

(sketch of proof below)

Define for $0<r<\delta$ the projection map: $\psi_r: U \mapsto \overline{U_r}$ given by $\psi_r(x)=x$ for $x\in \overline{U_r}$ and when $x=\phi(q,t)$ with $(q,t)\in T$ and $0<t<r$ we set $\psi_r(x)=\phi(q,r)$.
The map $\psi_r$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Claim 1: $\overline{U_r}$ is path connected. Proof: Let
$x,y\in \overline{U_r}$ and let $\gamma:[0,1]\to U$ be a path connecting $x$ and $y$ in $U$. Then $\psi_r\circ \gamma$
is a path connecting $x$ and $y$ in $\overline{U_r}$.

Claim 2:  $U_\epsilon$ is path connected for any $0<\epsilon<\delta$. Proof: Let $x,y\in U_\epsilon$. Then
$x,y\in \overline{U_r}$ for some $r\in(\epsilon,\delta)$. Then the path constructed in Claim 1 will also connect $x$ and $y$ in $U_\epsilon$.

---

Proving points 1. and 2. concerning $\phi$ are quite messy (at least I don't know any short and easily readable proofs).

Some steps in a proof could look like:

-- Local coordinates:  Pick $q_0\in\partial U$ and an o.n.b for $T_{q_0}\partial U$:
$e_1,...,e_{n-1}$.  Together with $e_n=N(q_0)$ we obtain an o.n.b for ${\Bbb R}^n$.

-- In this basis we write $(x,t)=(x_1,...,x_{n-1},t)\in {\Bbb R}^n$ for
the coordinates. In a small enough neighborhood of $q_0$, the boundary is
the graph of a map $t=f(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$ for which $f(0)=0$ and $\nabla f(0)=0$. We assume $f \in C^2$.
A point on the
surface is given by $q(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k e_k+f(x)e_n$ and finally in these local coordinates the map $phi$ takes the form:
$\phi(q(x),t)= q(x) + t N(q(x))$.
You verify that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial(x,t)}_{(0,0)} = (e_1,...,e_n)$ which is invertible. Thus $\phi$ defines a local diffeomorphism.

Now, using that $f$ is $C^2$ we may show that for $t>0$ small enough,
$B(q+tN(q),t)\subset U$ and
$\partial B(q+tN(q),t)\cap \partial U =\{q\}$.
($t$ should be smaller than the smallest radius of curvature
of $\partial U$ in a neighborhood of $q$,
but you also have to worry about the distance to other
parts of $\partial U$).
Then $q\in \partial U$ is the unique point in the
boundary closest to $q+tN(q)$ and their distance is precisely $t$.

Using compactness (and  choosing $\delta>0$ small enough), $\phi$ becomes a well defined map on $T_\delta$ and verifies the stated
properties.

Comment: Could you please add short proofs for properties $1$ and $2$ regarding $\phi$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am still a bit unsure how to finish the proof (second to last paragraph), but it should not be that difficult.

Comment: You are welcome. For the second last paragraph you may use that locally $|f(x)|\leq C\|x\|^2$ to see that  (locally) $\|(x,t-f(x))\|^2 \geq t^2  + \|x\|^2- 2t \; f(x) \geq t^2$ provided $2tC<1$. This yields that $q(0)$ is the closest point on this part of the surface to $q(0)+tN(0)$. It becomes 'muddy' because you have to worry globally about other points being closer. That's why I formulated in terms of balls being in $U$ (and only touching at $q$).

Comment: Thank you for the extended explanation!